# What kind of medicine would you pack for a 7yrs old first flight?

Tags: air-travel, children, hungary, health

I mean the flight itself. We have something against nausea (Daedalon) and I am trying to find something for a stuffy nose but since I am more Canadian now than Hungarian I have some difficulty figuring this out. Any good tips?

Comment: None, unless the child has a medical condition that requires some? What exactly are you trying to treat?

Comment: Ask your doctor, what he recommends.

Comment: @CMaster: I don't know about you, but when I travel, I bring along various common over-the-counter medications (ibuprofen, Pepto-Bismol, cortisone cream, etc) to treat various common conditions that I may not have now, but may arise unexpectedly (headache, indigestion, insect bite, etc).  Wouldn't it be reasonable to have an analogous list for a child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are better off asking a doctor this.

A child often needs medication labelled for children and it's important you do not give him an adult dosage.

Does your child have the flu? Or are you trying to pack medication 'just in case'? If he has a runny nose I would recommend a simple salt based nose spray, if he has no complications at all and you are just trying to prepare, don't bother.

Comment: +1 for if he has no complications, don't bother.

Comment: I am just trying to prepare. And I can read the product labels fine, I still speak Hungarian, I lived here for thirty years (alas).

Comment: @chx it's not clear what you are trying to prepare for though. Healthy humans don't spontaneously need medical care mid flight, even young ones. Equalizing ear air pressure is normally one of the most difficult things for children, but that doesn't need medication either.

Comment: Do not use travel sickness medication unless he is prone to travel sickness and has good reactions on the medication. (I was always car sick, but much worse when given medication.) Flying it a different kind of motion, very gentle, it is very likely he does not need motion sickness medication at all.

Answer (score 4):

Our four year old has two long haul trips under her belt (SE Asia to Africa, SE Asia to America).  We don't take anything different for the flights than we take for a road trip.

She gets a little anti-nausea medicine before the flight (because as an infant she got car sick) and that's it. But we have been cutting that dose down each trip, come March when we fly to the states we will try without.

I don't give her any congestion medicine unless she was suffering from a head cold.

But for your child, a discussion with your family doctor is the best course of action, as your physician knows the child's weaknesses and strengths when it comes to health.

Comment: Good on cutting down the travel sickness medication. Many children grow over their travel sickness. Just remember that any illness may give a temporary setback on growing out. (I still get sick a couple of weeks after a flu while grown out of normal travel sickness at about 16.)